# Поддерживает ли pyqtdeploy pyqt6?

Tags: android, qt, pyqt6

Собственно, вопрос - поддерживает ли pyqtdeploy pyqt6?

По поводу pyqt5 знаю, что да, а насчет pyqt6 не могу найти информацию.

Конечная цель - развертывание приложения на pyqt6 под андроид.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ознакомиться с официальной [документацией](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/pyqtdeploy/introduction.html), то можно увидеть, что последняя поддерживаемая версия PyQt - PyQt5

Используйте [**androiddeployqt**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-deploy-qt-tool.html)